# How do you create a blog post in rails without a topic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a Ruby on Rails course and I am on a part where I am trying to create a blog post but it is giving me an error. It says:

---

`1 error prohibited this blog from being saved:`

- Topic must exist

---

[my code](https://github.com/griggril000/DevcampPortfolio/tree/controller)

---

What do I change to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Blog` model you can add:

```
belongs_to :topic, optional: true
```

This will remove the validation check for your `Topic` association.

Here are the docs on [optional](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional). Keep in mind this is *if* you want to have a `Blog` save without a `Topic`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But I still don't have a topic text box if I want to type in a topic. How do I add that?

Comment: Do you want there *always* to be a topic?

Comment: No. I want to have an option for a topic but I want it to still publish if I don't have one.

Comment: It will work without a topic. It would just be nice to have a spot for one. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can force saving like so:

```
post.save(validate: false)
```

Comment: Where would I put that code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put topic_id since blog post belongs_to topic
here is how

inside app/views/blogs/_form.html.erb add f.select to choose topic (I copied the code from the link that you passed)

```
<%= form_with(model: blog, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if blog.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(blog.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this blog from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% blog.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= form.select :topic_id, Topic.pluck(:title, :id).sort, include_blank: false %>  


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :blog_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body, id: :blog_body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I just got an error that said `undefined local variable or method 'f' for #<#<Class:0x007f9a0d8a7038>:0x007f9a0da71210>`

Comment: ups sorry , you using form for the blog, I just changed my answer from f.select to form.select

Comment: Now it says `undefined method 'uniq' for #<Class:0x007f9a0daaea20>`

Comment: uniq is just to make sure for double Topic only show one times, you can remove it , and make sure you have at least one record for Topic

Comment: It still says `1 error prohibited this blog from being saved:`

-Topic must exist

Comment: What do you mean by having at least one record for topic?

Comment: run rails console, type Topic.all, check whether it has content, you cannot create "a child" without "parent" exist first, = you cannot create a blog without topic has minimal one record to choose